# How to change ctime to normal string representation?

Tags: perl

Using [`File::stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) we can get the `ctime` of a given file. My question is how to change the `ctime`, which means the inode change time in seconds since the epoch, to a normal  time representation like "2009-08-26 17:28:28". Is there any build-in or module can solve this task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most standard way is to use POSIX module and it's strftime function.

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use File::stat;

my $stat_epoch = stat( 'some_file.name' )->ctime;
print strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime( $stat_epoch ) );
```

All these markers like %Y, %m and so on, are defined in standard, and work the same in C, system "date" command (at least on Unix) and so on.

Comment: strftime is the way to go. Not much fuss, and lots of flexibility in output format.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is a human-readable representation, then

```
print scalar localtime stat($filename)->ctime;
```

will do the job. This prints something like "`Wed Jun 10 19:25:16 2009`".
You can't influence the format, though.
If you want the time in GMT, use "`scalar gmtime`" instead.

This is a special behaviour of [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) and [gmtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html) in scalar context.

Answer (score 0):

```
use DateTime;
$dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch );
```

The datetime object then contains the representations you require, e.g. `$year   = $dt->year;` etc. In scalar context you get a nice human-readable representation, e.g.

```
$epoch = 123456789;
$dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch );
print $dt;

1973-11-29T21:33:09
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in  Time::localtime perldoc for using it's ctime() to do this sort of thing.

```
use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;

my $date_string = ctime(stat($file)->ctime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::stat;
use Time::CTime;

$file = "BLAH BLAH BLAH";

$st = stat($file) or die "No $file: $!";
print strftime('%b %o', localtime($st->ctime));

#Feb 11th, for example.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the number of answers here, you have lots of options. I like the `Date::Format` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Format;
use File::Stat;

my $fs = File::Stat->new( '.vimrc' );
my $mtime = $fs->ctime();
print time2str( "changed in %Y on %B, %o at %T\n", $mtime );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you really using [`File::Stat`](http://search.cpan.org/~makoto/File-Stat-0.01/Stat.pm) rather than [`File::stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html)? If so, and if you have 5.8 or greater, switch to `File::stat`.

[`perldoc localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html)

> - `localtime EXPR`
> - `localtime`
>
>   Converts a time as returned by the time function to a 9-element list with the time analyzed for the local time zone.

...

> In scalar context, `localtime()` returns the `ctime(3)` value:

Once you realize that`localtime` can take an argument, then your mind opens up to all the other possibilities mentioned in this thread.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

my $stat = stat 't.pl';

print "$_\n" for $stat->ctime, scalar localtime($stat->ctime);
```

Comment: Holy crap! I edited the question and replaced File::stat with File::Stat. Undoing that change now.