# File creatiion date in ddmmyy format in perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I want to know how can i get file creation date in DDMMYYYY format.
I have tried this code but it does not meet my epxectations..

```
$creationtime=ctime(stat($filen)->ctime);
print "File was created on $creationtime\n";
```

Output is not in DDMMYYY format. It is printing time also. I just want date only and that too in DDMMYYYY format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctime` returns an epoch value.  To get an alternate format, you must convert it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat
use Time::Piece;

my $creationtime = localtime( stat($filename)->ctime )->strftime("%d%m%Y");
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333463/how-to-change-ctime-to-normal-string-representation):

```
use POSIX qw (strftime);
use File::stat;

$creationtime = stat($filen)->ctime; # in Unix epoch representation

print "File was created on ", strftime ('%d%m%Y', localtime $creationtime), "\n";
```

or

```
$creationtime = strftime ('%d%m%Y', localtime stat($filen)->ctime); # in DDMMYYYY representation

print "File was created on $creationtime\n";
```

Comment: Your code is working correctly but i need to store the creation time also in a variable.

Comment: I edited the answer, the second option is what you need.